# What size wire do I use?

Tags: electrical

I need to run wire underground, in conduit to my chicken coop for two light bulbs, a fan, and in winter a oil-filled heater.  What size wire do I use?  It's on a 20 amp breaker.   Approx distance from breaker box to chicken coop is 40 feet.

Comment: How long is the run? How much current/wattage does each device draw? What size breaker is protecting the circuit? Are you planning to run a single circuit (maybe a multi-wire branch circuit), or do you want to install a distribution panel at the chicken coop?

Answer (score 2):

The wire size depends on the breaker. Since you did not provide the size of the heater I would suggest 20 amp breaker with #12 wire. #14 with a 15 amp breaker may be large enough if the heater is a small one under 1000w. You should use a GFCI outlet or breaker.